# OpenGL Clip Space Frustum Culling Wrong Results

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I implemented a Clip-Space Frustum Culling on the CPU.
In a simple reduced case, I just create a rectangle based on 4 different points which I'm going to render in GL_LINES modes.

But sometimes, it seems to me, I get wrong results. Here is an example:

[image]

In this render pass, my frustum culling computation detects, all points would be outside the positive y coordinate in NDC coordinates.

Here is the input:

Points:

```
P1: -5000, 3, -5000
P2: -5000, 3,  5000
P3:  5000, 3,  5000
P4:  5000, 3, -5000
```

MVP (rounded):

```
  1.0550   0.0000  -1.4521   1138.9092
 -1.1700   1.9331  -0.8500  -6573.4885
 -0.6481  -0.5993  -0.4708  -2129.3858
 -0.6478  -0.5990  -0.4707  -2108.5455
```

And the calculations (MVP * Position)

```
P1       P2       P3       P4
3124     -11397   -847     13674
3532     -4968    -16668   -8168
3463     -1245    -7726    -3018
3482     -1225    -7703    -2996
```

And finally, transformed by the perspective divide (w-component)

```
P1       P2       P3       P4
0.897    9.304    0.110    -4.564
1.014    4.056    2.164    2.726
0.995    1.016    1.003    1.007
1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
```

As you can see, all transformed points have their y component greater than 1 and should be outside the Viewing Frustum.

I already double checked my matrices. I also made a transform feedback in the Vertex Shader to be sure, I use the same matrices for computation on CPU and GPU. Even the result of MVP * Point is the same in my Vertex Shader as on the GPU. My rendering pipeline is as simple as possible.

The vertex Shader is

```
vColor = aColor; 
gl_Position = MVP * aVertexPosition;

//With Transform Feedback enabled
//transOut = MVP * aVertexPosition
```

And the fragment Shader

```
FragColor = vColor;
```

So the Vertex Shader has the same results as my CPU computations.
But still, they are lines drawn on the screen!
Any Ideas why there are lines?
Do I do something wrong with the perspective divide?

What do I have to do, to detect, that this rectangle should not be culled, because there is at least one line visible (basically a strip of another line is visible as well in this example)

If it helps: The visible red line is the one between P1 and P2...

**[Edit]** Now I implemented a world space culling by computing the camera frustum normals and hesse normal form equations. This works fine with correct recognition. Sadly I do need correct computations in clip space, since I'm going to make other computations with that points. Someone any ideas?

Here is my computation code:

```
int outOfBoundArray[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
std::vector<glm::dvec4> tileBounds = activeElem->getTileBounds(); //Same as I use for world space culling
const glm::dmat4& viewProj = cam->getCameraTransformations().viewProjectionMatrix; //Same camera which I use for world space culling.

for (int i=0; i<tileBounds.size(); i++) {

    //Apply ModelViewProjection Matrix, to Clip Space
    glm::dvec4 transformVec = viewProj * tileBounds[i];

    //To NDC space [-1,1]
    transformVec = transformVec / transformVec[3];

    //Culling test
    if ( transformVec.x >  1.0 ) outOfBoundArray[0]++;
    if ( transformVec.x < -1.0 ) outOfBoundArray[1]++;
    if ( transformVec.y >  1.0 ) outOfBoundArray[2]++;
    if ( transformVec.y < -1.0 ) outOfBoundArray[3]++;
    if ( transformVec.z >  1.0 ) outOfBoundArray[4]++;
    if ( transformVec.z < -1.0 ) outOfBoundArray[5]++;

    //Other computations...
}

for (int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    if (outOfBoundArray[i] == tileBounds.size()) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem would appear that the sign of w (the third component) is different between P1 and P2. This will cause all kinds of trouble due to the nature of projective geometry.

Even though the points are on the same side of the NDC, the line that gets drawn actually goes through infinity: consider what happens when you linearly interpolate between P1 and P2 and do the division by w at each point separately; what happens is that when w approaches zero, the y value is not exactly zero and therefore the line zooms off to infinity. And then wraps around from the other side.

Projective geometry is a weird thing :)

But, for a solution, make sure that you clip those lines that cross the w=0 plane at the positive side of that plane, and you are set - your code should then work.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about that, but then I thought, the hardware also just does the perspective divide by w. But yeah, you're right, it's called clip space before the NDC space, so probably hardware does the same before the perspective divide. I will try to implement this and check if it works.

Comment: Yes, the hardware goes to lots of pains to make sure the lines that get drawn are the real ones even if w is negative somewhere; otherwise you would get really weird perspective effects when some of the points of a triangle would be behind your back.

Comment: My problem is the following: I want to estimate the rectangle size in screen space after Culling. If the perspective divide is not working that easy and I need to do clipping first, it's pretty hard to estimate the size, isn't it? Do you have any references (paper) for getting into it?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "size" - the number of pixels the image of it will cover or the largest magnification factor or what exactly?

Comment: Yes exactly. I'm writing a LOD based Terrain-Rendering. I have the LOD levels and bounding boxes for them. So I want to compute the bounding box size in the view frustum. If I see, it will cover less than 512 pixel in width and less than 512 in height, I'm not going to refine it anymore, since a tile is already represented by 512*512 triangles and therefore 512*512*2 triangles. There is no need to have multiple triangles for just 1 pixel viewfrustum...

Comment: Actually, you probably want the largest magnification, not pixel size, in this case. Consider the situation where you are near the edge of a tile, looking outwards, but see a small fragment of that tile from very close at one corner. You *should* refine in this situation, since you are seeing those pixels from very close up, even though you could be seeing less than 512*512 pixels. And this is actually something you can compute from the 3D distance to the box.

Comment: yeah my thouhgts were a bit different. I thought, I estimate the size in screen space, but not in visible space. More like: I don't care if it's outside the frustum. So the tile would need for example 6000*6000, but also if I just see 10*10, I would refine, because in 2D Space, it's larger